# A cross-entropy loss explanation in simple words

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, rnn

Suppose I build a FNN model. The last layer is a classification layer with softmax activation.
A cross-entropy loss is used to classify a problems, such as logistic regression. 
How would I calculate the cross entropy loss ?

But I can not fully understand the cross-entropy loss Please any convenient explanation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-entropy loss explanation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20296/cross-entropy-loss-explanation)