# Tensorflow keras fit - accuracy and loss both increasing drastically

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, accuracy

ubuntu - 20.04

tensorflow 2.2

dataset used = MNIST

I am testing tensorflow and i notice that validation `sparse_categorical_accuracy` (accuracy) and validation `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` (loss) both are increasing together which, does not make sense to me. I think the validation loss should be going down and validation accuracy increasing as the training progresses. Or, incase of overfitting, validation loss increasing and validation accuracy going down. But, validation loss and validation accuracy both are increasing as the training progresses. The training schedule however, is progressing according to expectation i.e training loss going down and training accuracy going up

Here is the code and the output:

```
#testing without preprocess monsoon
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as k
from tensorflow.keras import layers as l
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_t,y_t),(x_te,y_te) = mnist.load_data()
x_t = x_t.reshape(60000,-1)
x_te = x_te.reshape(10000,-1)

d_x_t = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_t)
d_y_t = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_t)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d_x_t,d_y_t)).shuffle(1000).batch(32)

d_x_te = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_te)
d_y_te = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_te)
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d_x_te,d_y_te)).shuffle(1000,seed=42).batch(32)

inp = k.Input((784,))
x = l.BatchNormalization()(inp)
x1 = l.Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='dense_1')(x)
x1=l.Dropout(0.5)(x1)
x1 = l.BatchNormalization()(x1)
x2 = l.Dense(512,activation='relu',name='dense_2')(x1)
x3 = l.Dense(512,activation='relu',name='dense_3')(x)
x = x3+x2

x=l.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = l.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = l.Dense(10,activation='relu',name='dense_4')(x)
predictions = l.Dense(10,activation=None,name='preds')(x)
model = k.Model(inputs=inp,outputs=predictions)

opt=tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage(
    k.optimizers.Adam(),
    True,
    0.99,
    None,
    'MovingAverage',
    clipnorm=5
)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=k.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
print('# Fit model on training data')
history = model.fit(dataset,
                    epochs=30,
                    steps_per_epoch=1875,
                    validation_data = dataset_test,
                    validation_steps = 313)

print('\nhistory dict:', history.history)
model.evaluate(dataset_test,batch_size=32,steps=331)
```

The learning evolution that i am getting is:

````
# Fit model on training data
Epoch 1/30
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/nitin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
1875/1875 [==============================] - 49s 26ms/step - loss: 0.3614 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8913 - val_loss: 0.3355 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9548
Epoch 2/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 49s 26ms/step - loss: 0.1899 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9427 - val_loss: 1.2028 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9641
Epoch 3/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1546 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9521 - val_loss: 1.6385 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9673
Epoch 4/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 38s 20ms/step - loss: 0.1357 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9585 - val_loss: 2.8285 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9697
Epoch 5/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 38s 20ms/step - loss: 0.1253 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9608 - val_loss: 3.8489 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9697
Epoch 6/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1149 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9646 - val_loss: 2.1872 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9699
Epoch 7/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1094 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9646 - val_loss: 2.9429 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9695
Epoch 8/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1066 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9667 - val_loss: 5.6166 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 9/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0991 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9688 - val_loss: 3.9547 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 10/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0948 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9701 - val_loss: 4.8149 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9713
Epoch 11/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0850 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9727 - val_loss: 7.4974 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9712
Epoch 12/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0879 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9719 - val_loss: 4.3669 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9714
Epoch 13/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0817 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9743 - val_loss: 9.2499 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9725
Epoch 14/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0805 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9737 - val_loss: 7.5436 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9716
Epoch 15/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0798 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9751 - val_loss: 14.2331 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9712
Epoch 16/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0745 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9757 - val_loss: 7.9517 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9715
Epoch 17/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0745 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9761 - val_loss: 7.9719 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9702
Epoch 18/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0741 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9763 - val_loss: 13.8696 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9665
Epoch 19/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0728 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9760 - val_loss: 20.2949 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9688
Epoch 20/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 45s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0699 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9775 - val_loss: 8.8696 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9713
Epoch 21/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0699 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9777 - val_loss: 12.9682 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9723
Epoch 22/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0674 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9781 - val_loss: 61.1677 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9692
Epoch 23/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0651 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9798 - val_loss: 21.3270 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9697
Epoch 24/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 31s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0624 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9800 - val_loss: 62.2778 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9685
Epoch 25/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0665 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9792 - val_loss: 24.9327 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9687
Epoch 26/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 46s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0605 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9805 - val_loss: 42.0141 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9700
Epoch 27/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0601 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9806 - val_loss: 54.8586 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9695
Epoch 28/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0583 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9811 - val_loss: 25.3613 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9680
Epoch 29/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0576 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9811 - val_loss: 23.2299 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 30/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0566 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9817 - val_loss: 16.5671 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9728

history dict: {'loss': [0.36135926842689514, 0.1898646354675293, 0.15456895530223846, 0.13569727540016174, 0.12525275349617004, 0.1148592159152031, 0.10943067818880081, 0.1066298857331276, 0.09912335127592087, 0.09476170688867569, 0.08501157909631729, 0.0879492461681366, 0.08170024305582047, 0.08047273010015488, 0.07976552098989487, 0.07453753799200058, 0.07450901716947556, 0.07413797080516815, 0.07278618961572647, 0.0698995441198349, 0.06988336145877838, 0.06740442663431168, 0.06507138162851334, 0.06242847815155983, 0.0665266141295433, 0.06050613150000572, 0.06005210056900978, 0.05830719694495201, 0.05763527378439903, 0.05664650723338127], 'sparse_categorical_accuracy': [0.8913000226020813, 0.9427499771118164, 0.9521499872207642, 0.9585333466529846, 0.9607999920845032, 0.9645500183105469, 0.9645666480064392, 0.9666833281517029, 0.9687666893005371, 0.9701166749000549, 0.9726999998092651, 0.9719499945640564, 0.9742666482925415, 0.9736999869346619, 0.9750999808311462, 0.9757000207901001, 0.9760833382606506, 0.9763166904449463, 0.9759833216667175, 0.977483332157135, 0.9777166843414307, 0.9780833125114441, 0.9798333048820496, 0.9800000190734863, 0.9792333245277405, 0.9805499911308289, 0.9805999994277954, 0.9810666441917419, 0.9810666441917419, 0.9816833138465881], 'val_loss': [0.33551061153411865, 1.2028071880340576, 1.6384732723236084, 2.828489065170288, 3.8488738536834717, 2.187160015106201, 2.9428975582122803, 5.6166462898254395, 3.954725503921509, 4.814915657043457, 7.4974141120910645, 4.366909503936768, 9.24986457824707, 7.543578147888184, 14.233136177062988, 7.951717853546143, 7.971870422363281, 13.869564056396484, 20.29490089416504, 8.869643211364746, 12.968180656433105, 61.167701721191406, 21.327049255371094, 62.27778625488281, 24.932708740234375, 42.01411437988281, 54.85857009887695, 25.361297607421875, 23.229896545410156, 16.56712532043457], 'val_sparse_categorical_accuracy': [0.954800009727478, 0.9641000032424927, 0.9672999978065491, 0.9696999788284302, 0.9696999788284302, 0.9699000120162964, 0.9695000052452087, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9713000059127808, 0.9711999893188477, 0.9714000225067139, 0.9725000262260437, 0.9715999960899353, 0.9711999893188477, 0.9714999794960022, 0.9702000021934509, 0.9664999842643738, 0.9688000082969666, 0.9713000059127808, 0.9722999930381775, 0.9692000150680542, 0.9696999788284302, 0.968500018119812, 0.9686999917030334, 0.9700000286102295, 0.9695000052452087, 0.9679999947547913, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9728000164031982]}
302/331 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 17.1192 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9725WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 331 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
313/331 [===========================>..] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 16.5671 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9728
[16.567113876342773, 0.9728000164031982]
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is due to a learning rate that is too high, it passes over the Loss function minimum and starts overshooting. Of course I can't be sure that's the reason but this is my best guess.

Try to simplify your optimizer, use `Adam()` optimizer alone (without moving average) and set a fairly small learning rate, something like `0.001` or even `0.0001`. Let's see how it goes and let us know.

Comment: I don't think the learning rate is too high as the train loss is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're just overfitting here. That's a fairly complex network for the simple MNIST data set. It's fairly easy to separate the MNIST classes, so even though your overfit network is starting to do worse on the validation set - it's getting less certain about the correct answers, believing the wrong ones more - the most-probable class is still almost always right. Accuracy is a function of the largest probability; loss is a function of them all. I would use val_loss here to decide to stop training earlier with early stopping.

Comment: Loss function (cross entropy) is also a function of the probability of the right class i think. cross entropy = $E_p(log(q))$ .. $p$ is 0 everywhere except for the correct class. Am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, as I say, loss is a function of probability predicted for all classes.

Comment: I dont see how though. It appears to me that loss is a function of only the probability predicted of correct class. For a sample with true labels as [1,0,0,0] the loss would be same if the predicted probabilities are [0.7,0.1,0.1,0.1] or [0.7,0.2,0.05,0.05]

Comment: No, that's not how log loss works. You have a term -log(1-p) for all true negative labels too. All classes have a term in the sum.

Comment: that is just the expanded form of cross entropy for binary problems. If you follow the maths you'll know what i mean. You can take help from this : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20296/cross-entropy-loss-explanation .. Also, please do let me know if im misunderstanding something

Comment: Hm I think you are right, I am not thinking it through. I think most of the original idea is probably on track - just getting less certain about the right answer while still being correct - but yeah the probability of the other wrong classes does not matter